# How to create a fake ToC on a title page?

Tags: table-of-contents, books, book-design, text-manipulation, etoc

I wrote a large book of 2000 pages, so I have to split it into 4 or 5 volumes of about 500 pages (250 paper sheets), for printing and paper binding issues.  Each volume would have its own front title page, designed from the code below.  It would be usefull to add a **Partial Table of Content** on it (the true and complete ToC is inside the first volume of the book).  Of course, each page number would be added by hand to these "fake ToC", since the title pages are done separately from the main document.  I would list only the chapters in these fake partial ToC, since they'll be shown on a single page.

So how would you suggest to build such "partial fake ToC", with the code below, in place of the dumb text part?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{1.5in}{1in}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{150, 170, 170}
\definecolor{andcolor}{RGB}{230, 255, 255}
\definecolor{subtitle}{RGB}{230, 255, 255}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\maintitle}{\begingroup

    \pagecolor{backgroundcolor}

    \raggedright
        {\hspace{-4pt}\fontsize{52}{0}\selectfont{Title 1}}

    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}

    \raggedleft
        {\textcolor{subtitle}{\fontsize{45}{0}\selectfont {Part 1 of 5}}}

    \vspace*{3\baselineskip}

    \raggedleft
        {\huge Author}
    \vfill

\endgroup}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
    \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
    \draw[line width = 1pt,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\maintitle

Dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text.

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Preview of what this code is doing, and the fake ToC emplacement shown in red:

[image]

Comment: Why not just take the `<filename>.toc` file generated by your document, chop it up appropriately, and paste it in? This seems to be a good time to actually call `\contentsline` by hand instead of leaving it in the background.

Comment: @WillieWong, how would you implement your idea?  Can you offer an answer, from the code above?

Comment: Say you want to include chapters 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 in this volume. Open up `<filename>.toc`, copy the lines that read `\contentsline{chapter}{....}` for those chapters, and paste them into where "dumb text" is.

Comment: @WillieWong, after a 3 pass compilation, the .toc document just disappears.  I don't get a remaining .toc file from the compilation (I just get a bunch of small or zero size files .out, .tex, .aux, .log, etc).

Comment: The `.toc` for the MAIN document. Not for the title page.

Comment: @WillieWong, this is exactly what I'm talking about.  I don't get any remaining .toc file after compilation of the full document.

Comment: How exactly is your main document getting its table of contents then? What is the document class you are using? I can't believe a 2000+ document with many chapters will have a "small" `.aux` file. Are there no lines like `@writefile{toc}{...}` in the `.aux` file?

Comment: @WillieWong, the full document is a book class.  The .aux file is just 4k on disk, and doesn't show any code related to the ToC (apparently).  And yes, my ToC is there and fully working.

Comment: @Cham: (1) Once you're done compiling (possibly via multiple passes), you must have a `.toc`. Sure, it's overwritten each time you compile, but it should be there once you're done, otherwise you won't have a ToC at all. (2) Do you compile each volume separately, or as a whole?

Comment: @Werner, I compile the full document in 3 passes, the whole PDF document is built in a single volume only (I prefer to split it at the printing level only).  And nope, no permanent .doc file here (it gets erased after the compilation, while many smaller temporary files are remaining there).

Comment: @cham: just checking, you are using the standard `\chapter`, `\section` commands for sectioning, and `\tableofcontents` to generate the ToC in the main document, right? Did you load some packages that may change how the ToC is processed? Are you using a build system that cleans up after itself? Plain LaTeX doesn't do that, and it is usually done by an external tool like `latexmk` or custom make files. // If you are using a build tool, you should change its configuration (at least temporarily) to stop doing that.

Comment: @WillieWong, yes, I'm using standard commands to add the chapters, sections, etc.  Of course.  I use some standard packages to change the display of the ToC, but just some easy tricks. I'm using pdfLaTeX.  My compilation app may be erasing the .toc after compilation, dunno why, while it leaves some other temporary files (until I quit the app).

Comment: @cham: "my compilation app"... care to enlighten us on which one it is? In any case, if you drop to a command line and just run `pdflatex`, you should be able to bypass whatever cleanup action your compilation app is using. (In fact, if the `.aux` files are kept, you should be able to just recover the `.toc` file with one pass.)

Comment: @WillieWong I'm using Latexian, on OS X.  It's the best user interface I've found, but AFAIK it is't developed anymore since a few years, I think.  I don't want to change that app, for at least another year, since I still have a lot of work to do with it, until I change my computer! I don't have time and motivation to adapt to a new environment.

Comment: @Cham: What is listed under the ["File Types" menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz4ge.png) (screen shot taken from LaTeXian 1.2)? Maybe there's something you can check to keep the `.toc`?

Comment: This would be easier to understand with a true MWE.  The example you've posted here doesn't have any toc at all (but a lot about the title page), so it's not clear (1) how your book's toc is generated, (2) why the toc file is no longer present, and (3) what parts of the main toc you want to appear in the subfile toc.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is based on the package `etoc`, with a two-step workflow.

I prepared a mock-up of a book with almost 2000 numbered  pages to get a significant TOC. The book has four parts with three chapters each.

I have defined the command `\fakeTOC` that adds an entry in the table of contents as it were a part. This is needed to later produce  the partial TOC by `etoc`.

The  page with the fake TOC is produced with your design using the command `\fakeTOC{<part name>}` and includes a partial TOC of the part of the full book, as requested.

These added pages  will not increase the page counter of the original content! In this way the partial TOCs will have the same page numbers for chapters as in the original document.

The local TOC is built by the `etoc` package. The layout of this local TOC is, of course, highly customizable. I only added the two horizontal lines.

The main TOC maintains the layout provided by the class.

**Initial TOC:** Full original document

[image: ori]

**TOC with fake TOCs:** after running `generateFkTOC.tex`.

Note that the chapter page numbers are the same as in the original table of contents.

[image: FK]

[image: newdoc]

**Extracted  pages with fake TOCs:** after running `extractfkTOC.tex`

[image: p4]

[image: fktocs]

As you don't want to have these "fake" pages in your main document, this is the two-step workflow:

(1) Generate them in the main document, adding  `\fakeTOC{<partnumber>}` at the beginning of each part  so that the local TOCs are *automatically generated and updated* by `etoc`. See `generateFkTOC.tex`

(2) Extract the four  pages generated containing the partial TOCs from the main pdf file, running `extractfkTOC.tex`

This is `generateFkTOC.tex`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage} % last page

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \, of \pageref{LastPage}}

   %%% ************************************
\usepackage{etoc} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\newcounter{fkpart} 
    
\newcommand{\fakeTOC}[1]{% % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\cleardoublepage    
\addtocounter{page}{-2} % decrease page counter
\addtocounter{fkpart}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thefkpart\hspace{1em}#1}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
\draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
\draw[line width = 1pt,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{backgroundcolor}
\sffamily           
{\raggedright\fontsize{52}{52}\selectfont  The Full Book}

\vspace*{2\baselineskip}
\raggedleft
{ \textcolor{subtitle}{\sffamily \fontsize{45}{45}\selectfont {Part #1 of 4}}}

\vspace*{3\baselineskip}

{\sffamily \huge Author}
\vfill
\localtableofcontents 
\vfill
Dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text dumb text.

\newpage\null
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{white}   
\endgroup
\cleardoublepage    
}
 %%% ************************************

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{150, 170, 170}
\definecolor{andcolor}{RGB}{230, 255, 255}
\definecolor{subtitle}{RGB}{230, 255, 255}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   

\begin{document}
    
\frontmatter    
\tableofcontents
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}

\etocsettocstyle{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vskip0.3\baselineskip\sffamily}%
{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vskip0.5\baselineskip} % etoc style for local TOC

\mainmatter
\fakeTOC{1}% part #1 starts
\chapter{I-One}
1.  \kant[1-5]  
\chapter{I-Two}
\addtocounter{page}{150}
1.  \kant[1-5]
\chapter{I-Three}
\addtocounter{page}{150}
1.  \kant[1-5]

\fakeTOC{2} % part #2 starts
\chapter{II-Four}
2.  \kant[1-5]
\chapter{II-Five}
\addtocounter{page}{350}
2.  \kant[1-25]
\chapter{II-Six}
2.  \kant[1-25]

\fakeTOC{3} % part #3 starts
\chapter{III-Seven}
3.  \kant[1-5]
\chapter{III-Eight}
\addtocounter{page}{350}
3.  \kant[1-25]
\chapter{III-Nine}
3.  \kant[1-25]

\fakeTOC{4} % part #4 starts
\chapter{IV-Ten}
4.  \kant[1-5]
\chapter{IV-Eleven}
\addtocounter{page}{350}
4.  \kant[1-25]
\chapter{IV-Twelve}
4.  \kant[1-25] 

\end{document}
```

This is `extractfkTOC.tex`. Uses the package `pdfpages` to extract the pages with the fake TOCs to a new pdf file. The page numbers are the number of the physical pages to be extracted from `generateFkTOC.tex`.

```
 %%% extractfkTOC.tex from generateFkTOC.tex

\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage{pdfpages}   
\begin{document}

    \includepdf[pages=3]{generateFkTOC.pdf} % use page numbers of physical pages
    \includepdf[pages=11]{generateFkTOC.pdf}
    \includepdf[pages=31]{generateFkTOC.pdf}
    \includepdf[pages=51]{generateFkTOC.pdf}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along the lines of having each volume a complete document file. Set the starting page/chapter etc numbers in the preamble of each document based on the last numbers in the preceeding volume to get continuous numbering through the group. Apart from the first volume any ToC will refer only to entries in the volume. For the first volume extend its *.toc file by the *.toc file of the subsequent volumes.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  Each title-page is done separately, independently of the whole document (which is a single PDF of 2000 pages).

Comment: @Cham I am suggesting that you make your single tex PDF document into multiple tex PDF documents, each of which have their own titlepage. At the end you can create a single PDF document by combing the individual PDFs.

Comment: This would turn into a nightmare!  The full document is huge, with a very complicated preamble.  I don't want to mess with it!

Comment: @Cham Tough --- GOM

Comment: GOM?  What is that?

Comment: @Cham  GOM = Grumpy Old Man.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, here's a quick and dirty way of doing what I need:

```
    \documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{libertine}
    \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage{anysize}
    \marginsize{1.5in}{1in}{0.5in}{0.5in}
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{150, 170, 170}
    \definecolor{andcolor}{RGB}{230, 255, 255}
    \definecolor{subtitle}{RGB}{230, 255, 255}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{afterpage}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    \newcommand*{\maintitle}{\begingroup

            \pagecolor{backgroundcolor}

            \raggedright
                    {\hspace{-4pt}\fontsize{52}{0}\selectfont{Big Book Title}}

            \vspace*{2\baselineskip}

            \raggedleft
                    {\textcolor{subtitle}{\fontsize{45}{0}\selectfont {Part 1 of 5}}}

            \vspace*{3\baselineskip}

            \raggedleft
                    {\huge Author's name}
            \vfill

    \endgroup}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
            \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
            \draw[line width = 1pt,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

            \maintitle

            \LARGE

            \raggedright
            Chapitre 1.  First chapter title \dotfill 1

            \vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}

            Chapitre 2.  Second chapter title \dotfill 83

            \vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}

            Chapitre 3.  Third chapter title \dotfill 109

            \vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}

            Chapitre 4.  Fourth chapter title \dotfill 179

            \vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}

            Chapitre 5.  Another chapter title \dotfill 269

            \vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}

            Chapitre 6.  Some funny chapter title \dotfill 399

            \vfill

    \end{titlepage}

    \end{document}
```

It isn't ideal, since I need to put back the chapter titles and page numbers by hand, but at least it's doing the job, and it's not too cumbersome to do since I have about 20 chapters, splited into 4 or 5 volumes (so 4 title pages to create like this one).  The first volume has the real title page (without a ToC on it!), and the real full ToC inside the volume.

Preview of this code:

[image]

Comment: I added a solution with an automatic generation of the "fake" TOCs.